# Angular 2 form <ng-datepicker> change event not getting detected

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Hi I am using the below code and I need the date selection to trigger a function. I am not sure what function to use. I tried the below list but none is working and I must use  Please review my code below.

```
<ng-datepicker formControlName="Date1" (select)="DatChange(myForm.value)">
</ng-datepicker>
```

Instead of (select) I also tried using (dateSelect), (onDateChange), (selectedChanged), (dateInput), (dateChange), (update), (change), (input), (onSelect) but none of these worked. Please help me out with the correct function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is currently it doesn't accept any function calls, I have added validations on button click to fulfil it....